# How to convert this image to json in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework

i take my picture with a camera after i want to post in the web service

so how to convert this image to format Json

my controller changed:

facebookExample.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location,$ionicPopup,$state,$http, Camera) {
        $scope.fileArray = [];
        $scope.imgContent = {};
        $scope.imageStrings = [];

```
  $scope.getPhoto = function(files) {
    Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
      console.log(imageURI);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
      angular.forEach(files, function(flowFile, i) {
      var uri = imageURI;
      $scope.imageStrings[i] = uri;
      $scope.imgContent = {
                fileName: flowFile.name,
                fileContent: uri
            };
         fileReader.readAsDataURL(flowFile.file);
         $scope.fileArray.push($scope.imgContent);

       });

    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });

    console.log("JSON.stringify($scope.fileArray)"); 
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.fileArray));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
$scope.fileArray = [];
$scope.imgContent = {};
$scope.imageStrings = [];

$scope.processFiles = function(files) {
    angular.forEach(files, function(flowFile, i) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(event) {
            var uri = event.target.result;
            $scope.imageStrings[i] = uri;
            $scope.imgContent = {
                fileName: flowFile.name,
                fileContent: uri
            };
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(flowFile.file);
        $scope.fileArray.push($scope.imgContent);
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.fileArray));
};
```

Or here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasdeepkhalsa/l5hmw/)

Comment: always is diplay this result : !JavaScript LOG: [ ]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and worked in one of my projects.Check it out.
Maybe it works for you too!

```
   $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) 
    {
                var promise = $service(imagePath);
                promise.success(function(data) 
                {
                    //after service
                });
  }, function(error) 
     {
                //An error occured
     });
   }
```

And here is an example service

```
  $service=function(photo)
    {
        $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

      var data=JSON.stringify({photo:photo});
      return $http.post("your webservice url",data);
    };
```

Edit 1:Forgot to give you the camera options.Here you are!

```
var options = {
                  quality: 100,
                  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                  cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT,
                  correctOrientation: true,
                  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                };
```